# converting a binary edge image to a binary mask in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binary, mask

I have a 2D binary edge image in MATLAB, i.e. a zero matrix just has 1 value in the edges of an elongated object like road or river. How can I specify 1 to all pixels between two edges of the river and 0 to pixels outside the edges. I use morphological `imfill` operator but It was not effective.

this is a synthetic binary edge image. I want to fill the inside of the curved event:
 [image: synthetic]
the result of filling the synthetic image:
[image: synthetic_filled]
the complex edge image is this:
[image: complex]
the complex edge image resulted from my method:
[image: complex2]

Thank you in advance

Comment: To get a good answer, please include the image you are describing, as well as how you tried to use `imfill` and why it didn't do as you expected.

Comment: @ Dear Prof. Luengo: I used just this simple command `BW = imfill(synthetic), but resulted in no changes in data.

Comment: @ Cris Luengo: I just specified some points by mouse and got good result. But, in a more complex image I have a problem. I want to keep only the edges of the river before filling them with a number of constraints, but I do not know what constraints should be used. could you help me please? I added complex image to the question.

Comment: and I encountered this error for the complex image: Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67%.  I could not to specify points by mouse.

Comment: Looking at your image, I don’t know what are reviews and what are not rivers, so I can’t give you any suggestions. River and road detection are well-studied subjects, did you do a literature search? Improving on state-of-the-art is good, reinventing the wheel is not.

Comment: you need to change your threshold while computing edges and you can try different filters like sobel, canny, rangefilt, etc. Use that filter which gives minimum gap in edges. I recommend you to use rangefilt function in matlab

Comment: @ Cris Luengo: I've already found a constraint on the road. First I have to apply connected component analysis, and then I should apply the compactness condition (the ratio of a region's area to the square of its perimeter). But before that, I need to fill in the edges. But unfortunately, I could not fill the complex edge image with BW = imfill(complex) command

Comment: @user8190410: I can compare my method with those methods. this is result of canny matlab edge function.

Comment: I added edge image resulted from my proposed method to the question. How can i fill in the edge and have a binary mask?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have holes in between your edges... try `imdilate` and then `imfill`

Comment: What SE should I use in `imdilate`? I don't want to increase the width of the curved event.

Comment: No "right" answer exists. Check different SE and see what is best for you.